1C Bitrix не показывает изменения контента без входа в админ панель
столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Есть сайт на 1С Bitrix, вношу изменения в шаблоны компонентов, добавляю CSS, однако при сохранении изменений измененные параметры отображаются только в случае, если я зашел в админ-панель, то есть в режиме инкогнито, просто в браузере без входа в админ-панель - никаких изменений не отображается. Но это касается только части сайта, отвечающую за основную часть контента. Изменения в хедере и футере - применяются и отображаются корректно.
Предполагаю, что дело в кэше (хотя, банальная очистка не помогла), может кто-то уже сталкивался с подобными проблемами?

Вопрос был в кэше компонента, почему-то не сработала кнопка очистить весь кэш. Но все решилось довольно банально.
